# Cannot convert value of type '(NSURLRequest, HTTPURLResponse?, AnyObject?, NSError?) -> Void' to expected argument type '(DataResponse<Any>) -> Void'

Tags: swift, xcode, alamofire

I study how to make iOS app by codingforentrepreneurs.com

nowadays I study Alamofire. Xcode is 8.3.3

this is error command. I don't understand error command.

> Cannot convert value of type '(NSURLRequest, HTTPURLResponse?,
>   AnyObject?, NSError?) -> Void' to expected argument type
>   '(DataResponse) -> Void'

this is ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire

    class ViewController: UIViewController {

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
            var rTest = Alamofire.request("http://ec2-52-78-193-10.ap-northeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com", method: .get)
            .responseJSON(completionHandler: isComplete)
        }

        func isComplete(request:NSURLRequest, response: HTTPURLResponse?, data: AnyObject?, error:NSError?) -> Void {
            print(response!.statusCode)
            print(data)
            print(error)
            print(request)

        }

        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
            // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
        }


    }
```

i don't know what is problem.
could you help me?

Comment: `AnyObject` and `NSError` looks like an outdated tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Signature of the completion handler method should be like this.

```
func isComplete(response: DataResponse<Any>) {
    let statusCode = response?.response?.statusCode
    let result = response?.result
    let request = response?.request
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error, in this case, correctly describes the problem.

The completion handler you passed in was of type `(NSURLRequest, HTTPURLResponse?, AnyObject?, NSError?) -> Void` but that is not the correct type for an Alamofire completion handler. The correct type is `(DataResponse) -> Void`

This means you need to change your `isComplete` method to something like:

```
func isComplete(dataResponse: DataResponse<Any>) -> Void {
    print(dataResponse)
}
```